# Нужна ли запятая?

Tags: пунктуация

Вступительный взнос(,) и порядок его внесения

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Вступительный взнос и порядок его внесения - однородные члены, союз И не повторяется,запятой нет

Comment: Спасибо! )

Answer (score 2):

Сложносочиненное предложение, но запятой нет, т.к. состоит из двух назывных, соединенных союзом И.